# Chrome Driver issues in C# selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I wrote my first selenium script and it worked.  here is the code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace test1Sel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\ChromeDriver");
```

If i try and write a new script however i get an error on the driver saying Invalid argument has been supplied.  I am using Visual Studio 2013 Pro.  I am not sure why the line worked the first time but will not work in any other script.  i have installed both selenium packages in the first script and in any other test script i have tried.  any ideas would be great!

Comment: Did you downloaded ChromeDriver.exe itself into that folder? Does it still exist there?

Comment: Yes it is downloaded and still exists.  the first script i wrote still works.  however any other scripts i try and write from scratch it will not work.

Comment: Please show more code. Have a read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace Chrome driver into the bin folder (solution\project\bin\debug), and use constructor without path (without arguments).

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```